# iPad trying to use GET method even though it's POST method

Tags: ios, ipad, http, post

I am using the following form for several months now, and noticed that in the last two weeks, some iPad devices (agent `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/5.1.42378 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4`) are trying to access `a.php` with a GET rather than POST, which I defined to return an 405 error, as I only want POST requests.

```
<form action="a.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="1"/>
<input name="b" type="hidden" value="none"/>
<input name="c" type="hidden" value="2"/>
<div class="button"><label><span class="icon"></span><input type="submit" class="button2" value="Click Here"></label></div></form>
```

Any idea what can be causing this all of the sudden?

EDIT:
This issue is still ongoing, anyone can tell the reason?

Comment: Maybe someone's trying to compromise your server by manually entering in the URL in their browser and analysing the response :D

Comment: nope, I can tell that the traffic is genuine, and it happens with various IPs, all of them are iPad users.